# Save hierarchical nodes from json file into mongodb using mongoose on a node server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a JSON file with a list of categories:

```
"data": {
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Clothes",
            "children": [
                "Womens",
                "Mens",
                "Children",
                "Baby",
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "13",
            "name": "Womens",
            "children": [
                "Womens Tops",
                "Womens Bottoms",
                "Womens Accessories",
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "33",
            "name": "Womens Tops",
            "children": []
        },
```

In the code below I tried/failed to iterate through each node and its children to build a `path` variable to also be stored with the data in the mongo db:

```
for(var i in obj.data.categories) {
    var newCat = {
        name: obj.data.categories[i].name,
        children: obj.data.categories[i].children
    };
    //UPDATE OR CREATE
    Category.findOneAndUpdate({name:obj.data.categories[i].name},newCat,{upsert: true},
        function(err,cat) {
            if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            if(cat.children) {
                //BUILD CHILDREN PATHS
                for(var j=0;j<cat.children.length;j++) {
                    var newChildCat = { 
                        name: cat.children[j], 
                    };
                    newChildCat.path = cat.path ? cat.path+','+cat.name : cat.name;
                    Category.findOneAndUpdate({ name: newChildCat.name},newChildCat,{upsert: true},
                        function(childErr, newChildCat) {
                            if(childErr) { return handleError(res, childErr); }
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
        }
     );
}
```

However, because javascript runs asynchronously, some node `paths` are being stored before their parent has been stored.

I am still kind of a newb at this and am looking for the proper/best practice way to handle asynchronous importing of objects that are dependent upon the previous creation of one another like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module to do this. The function you need is `async.eachSeries`

```
async.eachSeries(obj.data.categories, function(_cat, cb){
    var newCat = {...};

    Category.findOneAndUpdate({name:_cat.name},newCat,{upsert: true}, function(err,cat) {
        if(cat.children) {
          async.eachSeries(cat.children, function(_cat2, cb2){
            // the code like above with cb2()
          }, cb);
        } else {
          cb()
        }
    });

});
```